# Idea behind the proof of consistency of club filter of $\omega_1$ is ultrafilter + ZF + DC

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

I've been trying to understand Radin Forcing and some of its applications, one of which is the use of it to prove the consistency of ''Club filter of $\omega_1$ is an ultrafilter + ZF + DC''. However, Mitchell's proof in the paper "How weak is a closed unbounded ultrafilter" in logic 80' is a bit difficult to read. So this question is really asking for a potential outline from those who are familiar with this so I could try to recover the proof myself.

Thinking about this, the following is the big picture I had in mind (there are a few uncertainties and maybe mistakes I'm not aware of):

Start with a coherent measure sequence on $\kappa$, i.e. $\bar{U}$ (so $ord(\bar{U})=\kappa$) such that $U(0)=\kappa$ $U(1)$ is a normal ultrafilter on $\kappa$, and for $2<\alpha < length(\bar{U})  U(\alpha)$ is an ultrafilter on $V_\kappa$ satisfying the coherence property: $[id]_{U(\alpha)}=\bar{U}\restriction \alpha$ in $Ult(V,U(\alpha))$.

Radin poset with respect to $\bar{U}$ is $\mathbb{R}_{\bar{U}}$ consisting of finite sequences $p=((\bar{V_0},A_0),\cdots, (\bar{V_n},A_n))$ such that $A_i\in \bigcap \bar{V}_i$ and $\bar{V}_n=\bar{U}$ and $ord(\bar{V}_0)<\cdots < ord(\bar{V}_n)$.

Now we say $p<q$ if 1) each $(\bar{V},B)$ appearing in $q$, there is some $A\subset B$ such that $(\bar{V},A)$ appears in $p$; 2) for each $(\bar{V},B)$ appearing in $p$ but not in $q$ let $(\bar{U},A)$ be the pair appearing in $q$ such that $ord(\bar{U})$ is the smallest greater than $ord(\bar{V})$, then $\bar{V}\in A$ and $B\subset A$.

Say $\gamma$ is a repeat point if $\forall A \forall \beta A\in U(\beta) \Rightarrow \exists \gamma'<\gamma A\in U(\gamma')$. It is well known that when forcing with a measure sequence that has a repeat point, the measurability of $\kappa$ is preserved.

Now to get the desired model for ''Club filter of $\omega_1$ is an ultrafilter + ZF + DC'', assume that there are at least $\kappa^+$ many repeat points for $\bar{U}$, say $\eta_\nu: \nu<\kappa^+$. I want to iterate Radin Forcing $\kappa^+$ many times and then followed by a Lévy Collapse. The rough goal is that in the final model each subset of $\kappa$ appears at some intermediate stage, then the Radin forcing adds a club that is either almost contained in it or its complement, so then the Radin clubs do form an ultrafilter. Is there an explanation of the Mitchell's original argument that is more in the fashion of iterated forcing? Or more specifically,
do I use $\mathbb{R}_{\bar{U}\restriction \eta_\nu}$ to add a club at stage $\nu$? But this must damage some repeats points in the original measure sequence (since we need $\kappa^+$ many). For example in forcing extension with respect to $\mathbb{R}_{\bar{U}\restriction \eta_\nu}$, is $\eta_\nu$ still a repeat point and also $\eta_\mu, \mu>\nu$?

[Feel free to close it if the question is ambiguous, but I really had a hard time understanding Mitchell's argument].

Comment: Have you read the old paper by Spector (JSL 46 vol. 1 from 1981) where he does this from a supercompact?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes I did. I'm just not quite sure what would happen iterating Radin Forcing with sub measure sequences (if this is the right way to think about that).

Comment: You can not iterate Radin forcing in the usual sense even $\omega$-many times and preserve the inaccessibility of your large cardinal.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani I agree. I'm not quite sure what the corresponding support needs to be in the Mitchell forcing. Maybe full-support/Magidor iteration?

Comment: @Mohammad: Seeing how the end game is that the large cardinal is going to be $\aleph_1$, I don't know if that's a terrible thing after all. (But then again, I'm not the one person to consult about this specific issue...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but after $\omega$-many iteration, $\kappa$ changes its cofinality into $\omega,$ so if we collapse $\kappa$ into $\aleph_1,$ it in fact will be collapsed into $\aleph_0.$

Comment: @Mohammad: Sure, in the full generic extension. But can't you get rid of the collapse with symmetries?

Comment: No idea, but this can happen only if we ensure in the symmetric model $\kappa$ does not have cofinality $\omega,$ but in case of Mitchell, he adds the clubs into his symmetric model, so I think at least for this case maybe the answer is no; except we try a different symmetric model.

Comment: @JingZhang I think Magidor or Gitik iteration collapses $\kappa$ into $\omega, $ as Yair proved for the case of Prikry forcing. See ''[Questions about Prikry forcing and Cohen forcing](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164103/questions-about-prikry-forcing-and-cohen-forcing)''

Comment: @MohammadGolshani : Well, the argument may not be applicable (if the measure sequence has a repeat point it preserves the measurability of $\kappa$.). Also that only concerns the Magidor product of the same poset in the ground model. Whereas the case in the problem, we will have to choose a new poset (i.e. the Radin poset formed by longer measure sequence containing repeat points), so if these posets satisfy some conditions (as in the proof of consistency of "$\kappa$ is both least strongly compact and least measurable), then there might not be a problem. But I have to think about it.